# Некоректная компиляция коментариев в webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass, импорт

В файл `index.js` импортированы 2 файла **sass**

```
import './1.sass'
import './2.sass'
```

В каждом из них есть коментарии в начале

**1.sass**

```
/**
 * css 1
 */
body
  background: #000
```

**2.sass**

```
/**
 * css 2
 */
body
  color: #000000
```

После компиляции я получаю

**app.css**

```
/**
 * css 1
 */
body{
  background: #000
}/**
 * css 2
 */

body{
  color: #000000
}
```

Коментарий прилип к скобке предыдущего файла !

Можно ли это как-то исправить ?

Answer (score 1):

Надо добавить пустую строку в конце первого файла или не писать комментарий с первой строки.